# RS-DBI driver: (could not connect user@localhost:5432 on dbname "lahman": FATAL: database "lahman" does not exist

Tags: r, dbplyr

I'm trying to get the `lahman_postgres()` example from `dbplyr` to work, but I have not achieved to do so successfully:

```r
library(dbplyr)

lahman_postgres()
#> Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...): RS-DBI driver: (could not connect bs@localhost:5432 on dbname "lahman": FATAL:  database "lahman" does not exist
#> )

lahman_sqlite()
#> Creating table: AllstarFull
#> Creating table: Appearances
#> Creating table: AwardsManagers
#> Creating table: AwardsPlayers
#> Creating table: AwardsShareManagers
#> Creating table: AwardsSharePlayers
#> Creating table: Batting
#> Creating table: BattingPost
#> Creating table: CollegePlaying
#> Creating table: Fielding
#> Creating table: FieldingOF
#> Creating table: FieldingPost
#> Creating table: HallOfFame
#> Creating table: LahmanData
#> Creating table: Managers
#> Creating table: ManagersHalf
#> Creating table: Master
#> Creating table: Parks
#> Creating table: People
#> Creating table: Pitching
#> Creating table: PitchingPost
#> Creating table: Salaries
#> Creating table: Schools
#> Creating table: SeriesPost
#> Creating table: Teams
#> Creating table: TeamsFranchises
#> Creating table: TeamsHalf
#> src:  sqlite 3.29.0 [/var/folders/x8/gt429559287f1y6tjjtyc9vw0000gn/T//RtmpF1A7Xj/lahman.sqlite]
#> tbls: AllstarFull, Appearances, AwardsManagers, AwardsPlayers,
#>   AwardsShareManagers, AwardsSharePlayers, Batting, BattingPost,
#>   CollegePlaying, Fielding, FieldingOF, FieldingPost, HallOfFame,
#>   LahmanData, Managers, ManagersHalf, Master, Parks, People, Pitching,
#>   PitchingPost, Salaries, Schools, SeriesPost, sqlite_stat1, sqlite_stat4,
#>   Teams, TeamsFranchises, TeamsHalf
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The Postgres driver setup seems to be working:

```r
dplyr::src_postgres()
#> src:  postgres 11.4.0 [bs@localhost:5432/bs]
#> tbls: airlines, airports, flights, weather
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any ideas on steps I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a closer look at the implementation of `lahman_postgres()`, you'll notice that it calls `src_postgres()` with different arguments by default:

```r
dbplyr::lahman_postgres
#> function(dbname = "lahman", host = "localhost", ...) {
#>   src <- src_postgres(dbname, host = host, ...)
#>   copy_lahman(src)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x55c1e4643f90>
#> <environment: namespace:dbplyr>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

To troubleshoot errors in general, I recommend using `options(error = recover)` or enabling rlang's backtraces with [`entrace()` (see examples)](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/entrace.html#examples).